# How to record and replay http interactions?

Tags: router, http, port-forwarding

Is there a tool I can use in Windows to record and then programmatically (i.e. under a script or batch file) replay a specific interchange between a browser (either Firefox or IE) and a website?

Here’s my application: I want to set up a non-SuperUser’s computer to turn port forwarding on and off.  There are a variety of applications (e.g. certain games or VNC) that require this user to have port forwarding set up, but due to the security concerns, I don’t want to leave it on all the time (nor is there a predetermined schedule).  It occurred to me that I should be able to record the specific interactions I have with the webGUI interface to this person’s router to turn port forwarding on and off, and then set up a shortcut to an application that runs the script of those steps.  Basically, this would equivalent to a macro recorder, but for http.

I’m doing this on a Windows 7 machine that uses Firefox as the primary browser, but would be interested in solutions under XP or Vista.  The particular router in question is a Netgear (I can edit this to supply specific model), though if the technique I’m suggesting is feasible, the specifics of the router and its webGUI shouldn’t matter.

I tried locating such an application through Google and I did find [one possibility](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2004/06/04/recorder.html), but thought I might locate more/better options here.

Comment: why you don't use TELNET ? it let you manage the router via some sheduled scripts...

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use a web testing tool like [Solex](http://solex.sourceforge.net/). Most tools like this set themselves up as a local proxy and you configure your browser to use the proxy. This allows the tool to record the request and then execute it, returning the result to the browser.

There are also tools like [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [FireFox's Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966) plugin to capture requests, but I don't think they can do more than re-execute individual requests.

If those are too heavy for your need, maybe the [DejaClick plugin for FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3262) could record your interaction and replay it at will.

Answer (score 2):

Recording HTTP requests is not how that kind of thing is usually done; instead, there are tools that record and play back your interaction with the actual HTML pages. The currently most popular one seems to be [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you use an iPhone or iPad, you can try [HTTP Sniffer](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/http-sniffer/id451037645?ls=1&mt=8).

> HTTP Sniffer is a manual web security testing tool which can capture
>   HTTP requests, include request headers, post data, and you can modify
>   the request and then resend them.  You can get the response headers
>   and source code only, or load the response in web browser.

**Notice:**

1. Using HTTP Sniffer requires a network connection, and a Wi-Fi network is preferred.
2. HTTP Sniffer will not capture the requests of other applications, it capture the requests of its own only.
3. HTTP Sniffer is designed for web security professionals only, used for web security penetration testing, such as SQL Injection, Cross-site Scripting(XSS) etc.

[image]

**Key features:**

1. HTTP (Get, Post etc.) Sniffer
2. HTTP request replay (resend)
3. HTTPS support

Answer (score 0):

[JMeter proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) is going to do what you are looking for. You cold also use [Gor](https://github.com/buger/gor/) or TCPProxy, a that comes with the Grinder.

Comment: Please don't just link. Include the relevant information from the link. If the site ever goes down, your answer is useless. Read [answer].

Comment: If that website goes down than you cannot download the tools mentioned here and this information is useless. And I cannot add JMeter proxy nor Gor binaries to this post.

Comment: Hey, I like the fact that you contribute. What you contribute could just be a lot better. It would help to get more info as to how these tools answer the question. And the tools could be found elsewhere for download. If you want any upvotes, expand your answer. Again, read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Try http://autoqueue.net, you can record browser interaction and save to an XML based script. The script can be edited to run Javascript and used to generate screenshots and an HTML report for feedback.